# how to convert hex string to char array

Tags: c++

I try to read from file in specific position and than store these value in a char array.
But I have  to cast string into char array. I write a while loop for this purpose but code didn't into this loop.
Below , I shared an example hex file and a piece of code.
I would be grateful for any ideas or guidance.

hex file :

```
:100000004944542D434D58000000540044FC000066
:1000100000001120CCE6BDEEEC315000B0730000C2
:100020000000102037EF624040005000AC3100006B
:10003000BC3E0400261EA5BA000000003E9F10CB67
:1000400012000000ED901120600100000512112047
:10005000610100000512112064010000854B112090
:1000600065010100854B112066010000F14B112054
:10007000670100003D4C112068010000654C112013
:10008000690100008D4C11206C010000B11111209C
:100090006D010100B11111209201000081101120A9
```

Code:

```
string str1;

ifstream file("hexfile");

if (file.is_open()) {
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        string r = line.substr(9,32);
        str1.append(r);
        printf("%s\n", r.c_str());
    }
    file.close();
    printf("\n%s\n", str1.c_str());
}


uint8_t myhexarr [128];
int k;
istringstream hex_chars_stream(str1);
unsigned int c;
while (hex_chars_stream >> hex >> c) 
{

    cout <<"\n"<< c;
    /*
    some stuff
    ++k;
    myhexarr[k] = c;

    */
}
```

Comment: Forget the `hex` modifier and the formatting input, because they are useless. Just read two characters and convert them from hex yourself.

Comment: Not exactly, i can read file and it's okey. but ı store the reading hex data into a string. because i need to read a specific position (read up to 32nd character after the 9nd character) to do this i use substr. At this point, i  have to convert this hex string into char array, whic is the second loop i try to do this. but code didn't into this loop.

Comment: Even more so then. You've got the line in a `string`, so just iterate over that and convert the hex digits to numbers yourself. Putting them in an `istringstream` and reading them back is just making the code more complicated (and also a lot slower).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You may ignore very first block of code, it writes data to file, it is made just to make easy copy pasting whole example with test file, in your case you should delete this first block, because you already have input file and don't need to create it.

In my code as an example I truncate a string starting from offset `5` through `line = line.substr(5);`, you should modify this offset to your desired position.

I decode hex bytes manually in a loop.

Final loop in a code does output of integer values (bytes), you also should replace it with what you need.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/e34dY1d7K)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    {
        std::string text = R"(
:100000004944542D434D58000000540044FC000066
:1000100000001120CCE6BDEEEC315000B0730000C2
:100020000000102037EF624040005000AC3100006B
:10003000BC3E0400261EA5BA000000003E9F10CB67
:1000400012000000ED901120600100000512112047
:10005000610100000512112064010000854B112090
:1000600065010100854B112066010000F14B112054
:10007000670100003D4C112068010000654C112013
:10008000690100008D4C11206C010000B11111209C
:100090006D010100B11111209201000081101120A9
        )";
        std::ofstream out("data.hex");
        out << text;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream in("data.hex");
    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> result;
    while (in) {
        in >> line;
        if (line[0] != ':')
            continue;
        line = line.substr(5); // Cut line at necessary position
        if (line.size() & 1)
            std::cout << "Error. Line of odd size!" << std::endl;
        uint8_t byte = 0;
        result.resize(result.size() + 1);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
            char c = line[i];
            byte <<= 4;
            if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
                byte |= c - '0';
            else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
                byte |= c - 'A' + 10;
            else {
                std::cout << "Error. Wrong hex char '" +
                    std::string(1, c) + "'." << std::endl;
            }
            if (i & 1) {
                result.back().push_back(byte);
                byte = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto const & row: result) {
        for (auto x: row)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill(' ') << int(x) << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  0   0  73  68  84  45  67  77  88   0   0   0  84   0  68 252   0   0 102 
 16   0   0   0  17  32 204 230 189 238 236  49  80   0 176 115   0   0 194 
 32   0   0   0  16  32  55 239  98  64  64   0  80   0 172  49   0   0 107 
 48   0 188  62   4   0  38  30 165 186   0   0   0   0  62 159  16 203 103 
 64   0  18   0   0   0 237 144  17  32  96   1   0   0   5  18  17  32  71 
 80   0  97   1   0   0   5  18  17  32 100   1   0   0 133  75  17  32 144 
 96   0 101   1   1   0 133  75  17  32 102   1   0   0 241  75  17  32  84 
112   0 103   1   0   0  61  76  17  32 104   1   0   0 101  76  17  32  19 
128   0 105   1   0   0 141  76  17  32 108   1   0   0 177  17  17  32 156 
144   0 109   1   1   0 177  17  17  32 146   1   0   0 129  16  17  32 169
```